# .css is not a function error while using localstorage in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Actually I have created a nav-tab. What I want is that the clicked div of the nav-tab should change from white to black background and should stay black even after refresh until any other tab is clicked.

I tried code below but it throws error saying ‘.css is not a function’.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (localStorage.getItem("clicked")) {
    var clickedtab = localStorage.getItem("clicked");
    clickedtab.css(‘background’, ’black’);
  } else {
    $("#home").css('background', ’black’);
  }
  $("#home").click(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('clicked', $(this).attr(‘id’));
  });
  $("#profile").click(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('clicked', $(this).attr(‘id’));
  });
  $("#notifs").click(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('clicked', $(this).attr(‘id’));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <div id="home" class="menu_align active_one">Home</div>
  <div id="profile" class="menu_align">Profile</div>
  <div id="notifs" class="menu_align">Notifications</div>
</div>
```

Comment: var clickedtab=localStorage.getItem("clicked"); Here clickedtab is a String not a jQuery selector, obviously clickedtab.css() will give error.

Comment: Problem with `clickedtab`, you cannot use css function with variable

Comment: is this what you want ? https://jsfiddle.net/jzqa1wz4/

Comment: you should use single quotation instead of `‘id’`

Comment: So what should I do ? Any easy solution ?

Comment: @freedomn-m I mean `clickedtab` is not an element.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly note that you have several invalid quotes in your code. `‘` and `’` need to be replaced with `'`. Also ensure that the double quotes you use are valid too; they should be `"` only.

The problem with your logic is because the `clickedtab` value you retrieve from localStorage is the `id` *string* of the previously clicked `div`. You need to create a jQuery object from that in order to call jQuery methods, such as `css()`, on that element.

To do that you can concatenate the `id` to a selector and provide that as an argument to a jQuery object. You can also simplify the logic by providing a default value to the selector if nothing is held in localStorage, and also by using a common class to select the `div` elements, instead of repeating the same click handler N times. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var activetab = localStorage.getItem("clicked") || 'home';
  $('#' + activetab).css('background', 'black');

  $(".menu div").click(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('clicked', this.id);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="menu">
  <div id="home" class="menu_align active_one">Home</div>
  <div id="profile" class="menu_align">Profile</div>
  <div id="notifs" class="menu_align">Notifications</div>
</div>
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/9vm2zx08/)

Note the working example is in the Fiddle as SO Snippets have restrictions on accessing localStorage.